# extract specific value from json response using regular expression - latest

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

My last question was closed somehow. hence creating a new question.

I've the below JSON response received from the HTTP request. I want to extract the page number(i.e 1574) from the node. can some one please assist how to do it with Regular expression in jmeter ? or any other approach?

updated response:

```
 "links": {
        "first": {
            "href": "https://example.com/aaa/a/aa?page%5Bnumber%5D=1&page%5Bsize%5D=25&sort=-modifiedDate&page[number]=1",
            "rel": "first"
        },
        "next": {
            "href": "https://example.com/aaa/a/aa?page%5Bnumber%5D=1&page%5Bsize%5D=25&sort=-modifiedDate&page[number]=2",
            "rel": "next"
        },
        "last": {
            "href": "https://example.com/aaa/a/aa?page%5Bnumber%5D=1&page%5Bsize%5D=25&sort=-modifiedDate&page[number]=1574",
            "rel": "last"
        }
    },
    "meta": {
        "totalCount": 39334
    }
}
```

I have tried below data in Regular expression in Jmeter but could not retrieve 1574 value.

Regular expression: links.last.href.=(\d+)"
Template: $1$
Match: 1
Default value: pageno_not_found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is going for 2 [Post Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors):

1. [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide/) to get the `href` attribute for the "last" link:

   [image]
2. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to get the "number" from the variable generated by the JSON JMESPath Extractor

   [image]

Demo:

[image]